# How to check if the binary representation of an integer is a palindrome?

Tags: c++, c, binary, integer, palindrome

How to check if the binary representation of an integer is a palindrome?

Comment: Is 10001 a palindrome? Or does it have to be a full byte- 00100100? Or does it have to be a full int- 00000000 00000001 10000000 00000000?

Comment: So `0110` *isn't* a palindrome, because it's really `110`, right? Which implies that all non-zero palindromes are odd.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since you haven't specified a language in which to do it, here's some C code (not the most efficient implementation, but it should illustrate the point):

```
/* flip n */
unsigned int flip(unsigned int n)
{
    int i, newInt = 0;
    for (i=0; i<WORDSIZE; ++i)
    {
        newInt += (n & 0x0001);
        newInt <<= 1;
        n >>= 1;
    }
    return newInt;
}

bool isPalindrome(int n)
{
    int flipped = flip(n);
    /* shift to remove trailing zeroes */
    while (!(flipped & 0x0001))
        flipped >>= 1;
    return n == flipped;
}
```

**EDIT** fixed for your 10001 thing.

Comment: I like this solution due to its simplicity.  It's very clear both in code and algorithmically.

Comment: The number of bits in the integer (or whatever datatype you want to work with)

Comment: This code enters an infinite loop for isPalindrome(0x0); And I think it has an off by 1 error where it shifts newInt one too many

Answer (score 16):

Hopefully correct:

```
_Bool is_palindrome(unsigned n)
{
    unsigned m = 0;

    for(unsigned tmp = n; tmp; tmp >>= 1)
        m = (m << 1) | (tmp & 1);

    return m == n;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a 256 lines chart containing a char and it's bit reversed char.
given a 4 byte integer,
take the first char, look it on the chart, compare the answer to the last char of the integer.
if they differ it is not palindrome, if the are the same repeat with the middle chars.
if they differ it is not palindrome else it is.

Comment: This doesn't scale well -- are you going to use a 2 billion line chart for a 32-bit integer?

Comment: You don't need to - you only have to compare bytes at a time

Comment: Ah, of course. Of course, this doesn't work like he clarified.

Comment: this assumes the number is aligned. 101 is palindrome, but 0000 0000 0000 0101 is not.

Answer (score 2):

Plenty of nice solutions here. Let me add one that is not the most efficient, but very readable, in my opinion:

```
/* Reverses the digits of num assuming the given base. */
uint64_t
reverse_base(uint64_t num, uint8_t base)
{
  uint64_t rev = num % base;

  for (; num /= base; rev = rev * base + num % base);

  return rev;
}

/* Tells whether num is palindrome in the given base. */
bool
is_palindrome_base(uint64_t num, uint8_t base)
{
  /* A palindrome is equal to its reverse. */
  return num == reverse_base(num, base);
}

/* Tells whether num is a binary palindrome. */ 
bool
is_palindrome_bin(uint64_t num) 
{
  /* A binary palindrome is a palindrome in base 2. */
  return is_palindrome_base(num, 2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should be adaptable to any unsigned type. (Bit operations on signed types tend to be fraught with problems.)

```
bool test_pal(unsigned n)
{
  unsigned t = 0;

  for(unsigned bit = 1; bit && bit <= n; bit <<= 1)
    t = (t << 1) | !!(n & bit);

  return t == n;
}
```

Comment: +1; my answer uses the same algorithm, but instead of shifting a mask left, it shifts the value n right

Answer (score 1):

```
int palidrome (int num) 
{ 
  int rev = 0; 
  num = number; 
  while (num != 0)
  { 
    rev = (rev << 1) | (num & 1); num >> 1; 
  }

  if (rev = number) return 1; else return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Please make sure you properly format your answers so they are readable. All code should be indented 4 spaces. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I always have a palindrome function that works with Strings, that returns true if it is, false otherwise, e.g. in Java. The only thing I need to do is something like:

```
int number = 245;
String test = Integer.toString(number, 2);
if(isPalindrome(test)){
   ...
}
```

Comment: You "always have a palindrome function"?

Why exactly?

Comment: Maybe you got me wrong.
I mean that I have a palindrome function that works on Strings, and I can use it everywhere. Think once, use always.

Comment: The question is what is isPalindrome()'s implementation.  But, specifically, with binary representations.

Comment: String test = Integer.toString(number, 2);
With this, the number will be represented in binary.
The implementation is very simple. You loop till the middle of the String, and compare the char at the current position with the char on the respective position (test.length - current position). If they difer, you return false. When the loop is finished, you return true. =)

Comment: Raphael's answer makes complete sense, he just change the problem from working with binaries to working with a string, and solving if a string is a palindrome is fairly simple. The only caveat is that this question is tagged with c, c++

Comment: In C, you just convert the int to an array of chars, using itoa() (or the more supported sprintf()). After this, you just follow the previous steps. Quite easy =)

Comment: I agree with your approach. "The binary representation of an integer" is actually a string, in the same way as "The decimal representation of an integer" or "The hex representation of an integer" are. So dividing the problem into first obtain the string and then tell if it's a palindrome is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach is to start at the ends and work your way inward, i.e. compare the first bit and the last bit, the second bit and the second to last bit, etc, which will have O(N/2) where N is the size of the int.  If at any point your pairs aren't the same, it isn't a palindrome.

```
bool IsPalindrome(int n) {
    bool palindrome = true;
    size_t len = sizeof(n) * 8;
    for (int i = 0; i < len / 2; i++) {
        bool left_bit = !!(n & (1 << len - i - 1));
        bool right_bit = !!(n & (1 << i));
        if (left_bit != right_bit) {
            palindrome = false; 
            break;
        }
    }
    return palindrome;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't compile: bool right_bit = !!(n & (1 << i); is missing a closing parentheses. Won't this will break if there are leading zeros e.g: 17?

Comment: But it is strange we used the same versions almost (including naming). In fact, I ran your code against mine to determine differences and compiler errors.

Comment: Fixed the missing paren.  I am assuming, since the OP didn't specify, that the entire bitfield of the int must be a palindrome, not that we are ignoring leading zeros.  But now that you mention it, it might make sense to do it that way.

Comment: sizeof(n); gives you the size in bytes, you need the size in bits.

Answer (score 0):

A generic version:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
bool ispalindrome(T x) {
    size_t f = 0, l = (CHAR_BIT * sizeof x) - 1;
    // strip leading zeros
    while (!(x & (1 << l))) l--;
    for (; f != l; ++f, --l) {
        bool left = (x & (1 << f)) > 0; 
        bool right = (x & (1 << l)) > 0;
        //cout <<  left << '\n';
        //cout <<  right << '\n';
        if (left != right) break;
    }
    return f != l;
}       

int main() {
    cout << ispalindrome(17) << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's good to report a failure too;

There are lots of great answers here about the obvious way to do it, by analyzing in some form or other the bit pattern. I got to wondering, though, if there were any mathematical solutions? Are there properties of palendromic numbers that we might take advantage of?

So I played with the math a little bit, but the answer should really have been obvious from the start. It's trivial to prove that all binary palindromic numbers must be either odd or zero. That's about as far as I was able to get with it.

A little research showed no such approach for decimal palindromes, so it's either a very difficult problem or not solvable via a formal system. It might be interesting to prove the latter...

Comment: "all binary palindromic numbers must be either odd or zero" 0110 is neither odd nor zero, but can be considered a palindrome in base 2, it depends if you allow a palindrome to have leading zeros.

Comment: Decimal palindromes have exactly the same approach; all palindromes must not end in a 0 or be 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static bool IsPalindrome(int n) {
        for (int i = 0;  i < 16; i++) {
            if (((n >> i) & 1) != ((n >> (31 - i)) & 1)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that this question has been posted 2 years ago, but I have a better solution which doesn't depend on the word size and all,

```
int temp = 0;
int i = num;
while (1)
{ // let's say num is the number which has to be checked
    if (i & 0x1)
    {
        temp = temp + 1;
    }
    i = i >> 1;
    if (i) {
        temp = temp << 1;
    }   
    else   
    {
        break;
    }
}   

return temp == num;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bool PaLInt (unsigned int i, unsigned int bits)
{
    unsigned int t = i;
    unsigned int x = 0;
    while(i)
    {
        x = x << bits;        
        x = x | (i & ((1<<bits) - 1));
        i = i >> bits;
    }
    return x == t;
}
```

1. Call PalInt(i,1) for binary pallindromes
2. Call PalInt(i,3) for Octal Palindromes
3. Call PalInt(i,4) for Hex Palindromes

Answer (score 0):

In JAVA there is an easy way if you understand basic binary airthmetic, here is the code:

```
    public static void main(String []args){
        Integer num=73;
        String bin=getBinary(num);
        String revBin=reverse(bin);
        Integer revNum=getInteger(revBin);

        System.out.println("Is Palindrome: "+((num^revNum)==0));

     }

     static String getBinary(int c){
         return Integer.toBinaryString(c);
     }

     static Integer getInteger(String c){
         return Integer.parseInt(c,2);
     }

     static String reverse(String c){
         return new StringBuilder(c).reverse().toString();
     }
```

Comment: This is an interview question to test you about bitwise operations, and you are not meant to to use String or StringBuilder functions

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    unsigned int n = 134217729;
    unsigned int bits = floor(log(n)/log(2)+1);
    cout<< "Number of bits:" << bits << endl;
    unsigned int i=0;
    bool isPal = true;
    while(i<(bits/2))
    {
        if(((n & (unsigned int)pow(2,bits-i-1)) && (n & (unsigned int)pow(2,i))) 
                                         ||    
        (!(n & (unsigned int)pow(2,bits-i-1)) && !(n & (unsigned int)pow(2,i))))
        {
            i++;
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"Not a palindrome" << endl;
            isPal = false;
            break;
        }
}

    if(isPal)
        cout<<"Number is binary palindrome" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution below works in python:

`def CheckBinPal(b):
    b=str(bin(b))
    if b[2:]==b[:1:-1]:
        return True
    else:
        return False`

where b is the integer

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Clang, you can make use of some `__builtin`s.

```c
bool binaryPalindrome(const uint32_t n) {
  return n == __builtin_bitreverse32(n << __builtin_clz(n));
}
```

One thing to note is that `__builtin_clz(0)` is undefined so you'll need to check for zero. If you're compiling on ARM using Clang (next generation mac), then this makes use of the assembly instructions for reverse and clz ([compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/7GW9rK)).

```
clz     w8, w0
lsl     w8, w0, w8
rbit    w8, w8
cmp     w8, w0
cset    w0, eq
ret
```

x86 has instructions for clz (sort of) but not reversing. Still, Clang will emit the fastest code possible for reversing on the target architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript Solution

```
function isPalindrome(num) {
  const binaryNum = num.toString(2);
  console.log(binaryNum)
  for(let i=0, j=binaryNum.length-1; i<=j; i++, j--) {
    if(binaryNum[i]!==binaryNum[j]) return false;
  }
  return true;
}

console.log(isPalindrome(0))
```