# Bit operation equivalent of pop function in PERL(remove MSB)

Tags: perl, bit-manipulation, bitvector

In Perl, is there a bitwise operator that acts like `>>`, but removes the most significant bit?  Sort of like how the `>>` operator is somewhat like the `shift()` function, I'm looking for a bit operator that's like `pop()`.

`110110` would return `10110`

`101` would return `01`

Ultimately I'm trying to see whether a number in binary form is palindromic (i.e. 11011, 111, or 1010101), so ideally the operator would have a way of returning the bit it removes.  It's okay if the operator doesn't, as I could do so mathematically, but in the interest of clean code, it would be awesome if it returned the MSB automatically.  For the LSB, I do

```
$LSB=$mynum-2*($mynum>>1);
$mynum>>=1;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't think of a simpler way than just storing it as a string:

```
my $bits = sprintf '%b', $num;
while ( $bits =~ s/(.)// ) {
    print "removed $1\n";
}
```

though then your palindrome check is just

```
$bits eq reverse $bits
```

Answer (score 2):

see [How to check if the binary representation of an integer is a palindrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845772/how-to-check-if-the-binary-representation-of-an-integer-is-a-palindrome)

Comment: You know, I spent way too long looking for something just like that to not have found it.  What does WORDSIZE mean in that example?

Comment: @Ranting_Raven, I posted it in case you missed it. WORDSIZE is the size of a word on your machine (I assume)

Answer (score 1):

Since your values have variable numbers of bits you need a bit string or bit vector. Check out [Bit::Vector](http://search.cpan.org/~stbey/Bit-Vector-7.1/Vector.pod) on CPAN -- it seems to still be active.

But as the others have suggested for your problem it's probably easier for you just to deal with a plain old string.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Perl, but in C/C++ you'd do this like so:

```
unsigned flp2(unsigned x) {
   x = x | (x >> 1);
   x = x | (x >> 2);
   x = x | (x >> 4);
   x = x | (x >> 8);
   x = x | (x >>16);
   return x - (x >> 1);
}

unsigned most_significant_bit = flp2(my_number);
my_number &= most_significant_bit;
```

Courtesy of Hacker's Delight.

Note that to find the most significant bit in assembler you could use BSR, in MSVC _BitScanReverse, in GCC _builtin_clz. There are however no simple high-level (and portable) operators that I know of. Languages evolve much slower than CPUs and compilers.