# Strip leading zeroes in binary number in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, binary

Given an integer, how do I strip the leading zeroes off its binary representation?

I am using bit-wise operators to manipulate its binary representation. I am trying to see if an integer is a palindrome in its binary representation. I know there are different solutions out there but I wanted to compare the first and last bit, second and last but one bit and so on. So, I was wondering how to strip those leading 0's for this int.

Comment: Perhaps a silly question, but how are your getting its binary representation?

Comment: Using bit-wise operators to manipulate its binary representation. I am trying to see if an integer is a palindrome in its binary representation. I know there are different solutions out there but I wanted to compare the first and last bit, second and last but one bit and so on. So, I was wondering how to strip those leading 0's for this int.

Comment: You could try converting it to a string and using `std::string::find_first_not_of`.

Comment: I could but that would beat the purpose of checking this efficiently using bit-wise operators.

Comment: Duplicate. Check out this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845772/how-to-check-if-the-binary-representation-of-an-integer-is-a-palindrome

Comment: @sixlettervariables Look at his comment?

Comment: @JKD: Comments are not questions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `BitScanForward` and `BitScanReverse` (the exact names vary by compiler) to efficiently trim (well, skip processing of) zeros from either side.

Comment: Hi Ben, can you check if BitScanForward is really the function *f(x)* used to solve [this prefix problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2892097/70274)? (see penultimate paragraph at "conclusion").

Comment: @PeterKrauss: `BitScanReverse` is definitely useful for solving that with no loop, but your description isn't accurate.  `BitScanReverse` tells you how far to shift; it doesn't return the shifted number.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the first bit set by finding the [log base 2 of the number](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLogDeBruijn):

```
/* from Bit Twiddling Hacks */
static const unsigned int MultiplyDeBruijnBitPosition[32] = 
{
    0, 9, 1, 10, 13, 21, 2, 29, 11, 14, 16, 18, 22, 25, 3, 30,
    8, 12, 20, 28, 15, 17, 24, 7, 19, 27, 23, 6, 26, 5, 4, 31
};

uint32_t pos = value;
pos |= pos >> 1;
pos |= pos >> 2;
pos |= pos >> 4;
pos |= pos >> 8;
pos |= pos >> 16;
pos = MultiplyDeBruijnBitPosition[(uint32_t)(pos * 0x07C4ACDDU) >> 27];
```

Or if you need a mask, just adapt [finding the next power of 2](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#RoundUpPowerOf2):

```
/* adapted from Bit Twiddling Hacks */
uint32_t mask = value - 1;
mask |= mask >> 1;
mask |= mask >> 2;
mask |= mask >> 4;
mask |= mask >> 8;
mask |= mask >> 16;
```

Comment: `0x07C4ACDDU` Can you cite your sources?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using strings and performance isn't an issue you can do this:

```
    #include <bitset>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;

    // your number
    int N;
    ...

    // convert to a 32 bit length binary string
    string bitstr = bitset<32>(N).to_string();

    // get the substring
    int index = 0;
    string strippedstr;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < bitstr.length(); ++i) {
        if(bitstr[i] == '1') {
            index = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    strippedstr = bitstr.substr(index);
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer posted in [How to check if the binary representation of an integer is a palindrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845772/how-to-check-if-the-binary-representation-of-an-integer-is-a-palindrome)

You first reverse the bits using this function:

```
/* flip n */
unsigned int flip(unsigned int n)
{
    int i, newInt = 0;
    for (i=0; i<WORDSIZE; ++i)
    {
        newInt += (n & 0x0001);
        newInt <<= 1;
        n >>= 1;
    }
    return newInt;
}
```

Then remove the trailing zeros:

```
int flipped = flip(n);
/* shift to remove trailing zeroes */
while (!(flipped & 0x0001))
    flipped >>= 1;
```

To answer your comment about checking to see if the int is a palindrome, just compare the bit-shifted flipped version with the original:

```
return n == flipped;
```

Comment: I think this one is pretty ineffective.