# Most elegant way to check if a binary representation of an integer is a palindrome?

Tags: bit

What is the most elegant way to check if a binary representation of an integer is a palindrome? Suppose the integer is 32-bit.

Without shifting bits iteratively, can we achieve this? Any code snippet will be highly welcome.

I noticed the post [How to check if the binary representation of an integer is a palindrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845772/how-to-check-if-the-binary-representation-of-an-integer-is-a-palindrome), but it is done by bit shifting. Are there any other methods?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Elegance is in the eye of the beholder.

Answer (score 1):

This is really just a special case of [reversing bit order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746171/best-algorithm-for-bit-reversal-from-msb-lsb-to-lsb-msb-in-c) since any palindrome will be equal to itself once reversed.

One way or another, you have to reverse the order of the bits, which on some platforms is a single instruction.  See the linked question and pick the one you find to be the most elegant.

Comment: Thanks for the link. That really helps!

Comment: You may consider accepting the question or upvoting if you feels it addresses your question.  Click the checkmark or the arrows next to my answer.